# UriBuilder not combining two uris correctly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

So Here is my problem:
I want to combine a URI and a string. The URI is a path to a (parent) folder, while the string represents the path to a sub folder (don't ask me why I am doing this, both types need to stay that way for the rest of the program to function).

My Code:

```
private Uri BuildUri(Uri basePath, string resource)
{
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(basePath)
    {
        Path = resource,
    };
    return uriBuilder.Uri;
}
```

If I call this code with `basePath` being e.g. "D:\Test" and resource being "locations" the URI builder combines me those two to file:///locations and totally ignores the complete base path. I might add that `basePath` is always of type `UriKing.Absolute`

What am I doing wrong? If I do:

```
var completePath = Path.Combine(basePath.AbsolutePath, resource);
return new Uri(completePath);
```

It correctly returns a URI, but since Path.Combine has some problems in Live environments (namely permissions) I'd like to use the UriBuilder (which seems to be built for exactly the task I want it to perform).

Comment: `UriKing.Absolute` made me smile... The undisputed monarch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're combining the constructor and initialization syntax, which is overwriting the `.Path` property completely, not appending to it.

Essentially...

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("D:\\Test");
// uriBuilder.Path is now "D:\\Test"
// ToString() will give "file:///D:/Test"

uriBuilder.Path = "locations";
// ToString() will give  "file://locations", because Path is "locations"
```

If you can't use Path.Combine, you'll have to write your own Path.Combine.

In my very limited testing, `UriBuilder` seems to do the right thing if you just assume "/" is the directory separator.

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("D:\\Test");
uriBuilder.Path += "/locations";
// uriBuilder.ToString() == "file:///D:/Test/locations"
```

However, if `basePath` already ended with a "/" or "\", then you'll end up with double-slashes in your URL.  Technically, that's still a valid URL.  But it's ugly and someone will probably file a bug against you eventually.  You'll have to handle all permutations of `uriBuilder.Path` ending with "/" or not and `resource` starting with "/", "\", or not.

Comment: Doh! Yeah silly me. That was the problem. But how come the same approach works for HTTP URIs and not file URIs?

Comment: It doesn't!

What could be confusing you is that file:// URLs don't have the host portion of the URL in them, typically.  Changing the .Path will not affect the Hostname part of "http://foo.com/base", but the "base" part will be gone.

Comment: Yeah, that would be it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the base URI ends with a slash (or backslash), and the relative URI doesn't. It's the only way they will be combined correctly.

Comment: Does not work. My baseUri is D:\Test\ and my resource is "location", I also tried "\location" and the result is always: file:///locations

Comment: Jup that was my fault, Host didn't end with `/` so the last part of my hostname got cut off